# How to handle API responds with DTO or Error Message

Tags: .net, api, mobile, http-response

I have a mobile app and an API. The mobile app is set up to expect back a DTO from the API but has no information if an request was unsuccessful.
This needs to be updated so that better messaging is displayed to the user. I need to update the API and Mobile App so that I can send back a
DTO on a successful request or a message that contains more detail than a generic error message.

I have started changing the API return types to `IHttpActionResult` so I can pass the HTTP status code AND data.

My first thought is to create a request wrapper which will have an error message and a generic data object.

```
public class ResponseWrapper
{
    public bool IsSuccess{get; set;}
    public string ErrorMsg {get; set;}
    public Object Data {get; set;}
}
```

I can then check the `IsSuccess` flag and proceed accordingly.

I also thought about implimenting error codes or using custom HTTP status codes. But I feel this adds complexity with maintaining codes and
associated messages. With this preceived added complexity, this does not seem like the best solution.

Is there a better solution or one that is the standard practice for capturing a DTO or error message in the same api response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are using a HTTP API for the communication between the client and the server.

I can only advise you from my personal preference, from my conventions. I am used to take advantage of the HTTP vocabulary.

For UI server APIs I only take advantage of status codes. I keep things simple. For all successful requests I send back status code 200. The requests that change state on the server do not send anything back to the client. In some cases data is requred and I bend from this convention and still send, but very rarely. For requests that don't change state like GET I just send a json back with status code 200. Now for any requests that fail (because of the user or something else) I don't add any data to it, the status code is enough. Status code 400 = generic invalid action from the user (invalid input). Status code 404 for GET requests when data is not found. Status code 500 for generic server error. Status code 401 when a request is made that requires authentication.

As you can see there aren't many codes to keep track of. You just need to follow some simple conventions. My basic conventions : try to not return any data when the requests are changing state (POST). Use only those 5 status codes.

Now, with my developer APIs, those that are ment to be consumed programtically by third parties (not the client APP UI), sometimes I also tend to add custom message near the HTTP status code and there I sometimes user more status codes to make the devs life easier, because they tend to need more information from a HTTP response.

Now why for the UI things can be kept simple? Because you can do most validation on the UI / client side. No need to return error information to the client, validate a request before it's sent. The UI client generally just needs to know if it failed or not, no other details (except if it's the user's fault or the server's fault).

Comment: As a side note. When I say I don't send anything back I am refering that the response body is empty. Something is still sent back , the http headers and the status line